# Targeting propertry settings to .net 3.5 throws error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, .net-3.5, settings

I converted one of my project which was made with .net framework 4.5 to 3.5(VS2013 IDE) to make it compatible with Windows XP os.

Issues:

project loads set of values from 'project.property.settings at onload event and it throws error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll

Additional information: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for userSettings/Installer.Properties.Settings: Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

InnerException: When using relative path, make sure the current directory is correct.
InnerException:Verify that the file exists in the specified location
```

i search web regarding the problem but nothing works in this project and i also changed version to 3.5.0.0 in app.config file.

app.config file

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <section name="Installer.Settings1" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false"/>
            <section name="Installer.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false"/>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
```

program throws the above error while executing following coding in settings.designer.cs

```
public string c0 {
            get {
                return ((string)(this["c0"]));
            }
            set {
                this["c0"] = value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Check if there exist specific version of .Net, maybe its 3.5.1

Comment: check your project references, you should have a reference to the assembly System. Hit F4 (properties), and check the version of your reference. Also check if your reference is marked with a yellow exclamation point

Comment: @AdrianNasui yellow exclamation marks on Microsoft.CSharp, System.IO.Compression, System.IO.Compression.FileSystem. what are the references i should add in reference?